# CSS: How to position an <img> to the middle of the parent element

Tags: html, css

Here is the link: http://www.cssdesk.com/PYBRZ

Help, i can't make that  element (or any  with different sizes) to position itself to the middle of the parent element. I've been figuring this out for 2 days, still can't find a way to solve this problem.

---

Here is the updated link: http://www.cssdesk.com/W3MvQ

Still, it won't position itself to the middle, it just goes to the center :(

Comment: It would be helpful if you added some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#overlay {
    position:relative;
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#overlay img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    outline: 1px dotted yellow;
}
```

and look at the following jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/UwJZw/

**How This Works**

You set `position: relative` on the parent container (`#overlay`) and set the width to 100% and the height to 100%.  Note that for the height to work, you need to set the height to the root element (`<html>`) and `<body>` to 100%.

The trick is to position the `<img>` absolutely and set the top/bottom/left/right positions to zero, and then set margin to auto, and this will center both horizontally and vertically.

The bonus is that this works regardless of the size of the image, no math required.

I added a yellow outline so show the edges of the image, this does not affect the solution.

Note that depending on how much browser chrome in play, the 100% height may trigger the vertical scrolling bar.  You would need to ponder how best to design around that taking into account the rest of your page layout.

On the other hand, if you have fixed height container, this works like a charm, especially for photo galleries and so on.

This technique is based on CSS 2.1 so it should work in quite a few browsers.

Comment: You just got what I needed :D Thanks bro!!

Comment: Good luck battling litte geen CSS monsters and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1):

Give `margin:auto` to the image to **horizontally** center align.

```
.overlay img
{
   display: block; 
   margin-left: auto; 
   margin-right: auto; 
}
```

This is from W3C standards of centering image.. See this http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

For **vertical** alignment is not straight forward as your div is fixed positioned. Instead you can gove background to your div

```
background:url("http://oi46.tinypic.com/56612.jpg") no-repeat center center
```

Try this:-  http://www.cssdesk.com/nSyPa

```
<div id="overlay">

</div>


#overlay {
  background: black url('http://oi46.tinypic.com/56612.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index:1000;
  text-align: center;
}
```

You can also go with margin-top on the image but that will be more maintenance headache, and you have to calculate the margin based on various resolutions etc..

Comment: still, i can't center it both vertically and horizontally: http://www.cssdesk.com/W3MvQ

Comment: For vertical alignment, specify image as a background for your div

Answer (score 1):

THE OP MEANS VERTICALLY ALIGN TO THE MIDDLE PLEASE NOTE THIS ANSWER IS DIVIDED IN TWO:

What you need is kind of tricky. You need to know the height of the parent in order to apply either a margin-top, padding top or even with position absolute a top and left value;

Look at this for instance:

```
#overlay {

  background: black;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  z-index:1000;
  text-align:center;


}

#overlay img {
  margin-top:100px
}
```

With JavaScript you can dynamically detect the height of the parent so you can apply some styling to the child accordingly.

You can also leave the parent without any dimensions and add a specific padding, in that way the parent will take the size of the child plus a padding around:

```
 #overlay {

      background: black;
      position: fixed;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      z-index:1000;
      padding:80px;


    }

    #overlay img {
       /*nothing in here unless you need any other style*/

    }
```

FIRST ANSWER **

There are many ways, give to the parent the style `text-align:center`

```
#overlay {
  display: table;
  background: black;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index:1000;
  text-align:center;
}
```

or convert the image to a block with a specific with and margin auto:

```
#overlay img {


  display:block;
  width:100px;
  margin:auto


}
```

The default of an image is inline-block which makes it act as text, that is why text-align center to the parent works, on the other hand if you make it a block, with a specific with and margin auto you assure that it is not treated as text and will be centered in all browsers.

Since you have different sizes and can;t specify a width, just by doing the following works in your example, try it:

```
#overlay img {

  display: block;
  margin:auto;

}
```

Comment: it just moves to the center :(
I meant to the middle

Comment: Ohhh! you mean vertically!

Comment: Yes both vertically and horizontally

Comment: after i get the height of the parent element, how should i know how much margin-top i will give?

Comment: Well lets say that the parent is 800 and the child 600, then the difference is 200, so you need half of that, 100px margin-top :)

Comment: some img now goes right into place, but what happens is that if an img is bigger than the size of the parent :)) it is misplaced

like parent 800px, img 1000px (800 - 1000px) / 2
the margin-top is negative :))

i mean, how does fb do that? when you click an img on chat, it would appear to the center and middle of the screen, vertically and horizontally. I inspect the element and saw some vertical-align: middle, but it doesnt work when I do the same.

Comment: Aha! I know what you want to do, add a fixed padding to the parent, look at my answer again